# Syntax error assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
select sum(a.total) from (
sum(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal,
(select count(*)  from DBname where PCPriceTotal > 0 ) as total
from DBname group by PCPriceTotal) as a
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal, (select count(*) from DBname' at line 2

Solved. Simple error. Missed "Select". Fixed:

```
select sum(a.total) from (
select sum(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal,
(select count(*)  from DBname where PCPriceTotal > 0 ) as total
from DBname group by PCPriceTotal) as a
```

Comment: jam the word `select ` after the `from ( ` for starters. Then see what that leads to ... probably the next explosion, but heh.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put 'SELECT' in your subquery which is before `` SUM(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal ``.

```
SELECT SUM(a.total) FROM 
(SELECT
    SUM(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM DBname WHERE PCPriceTotal > 0 ) AS total
    FROM DBname GROUP BY PCPriceTotal
) AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

You  are using  function in place of table **(sum(`PCPrice` * TaxVariable) AS PCPriceTotal**,

What is you requirement.